# Custom event not being caught in directive

Tags: angular

Angular 9, I am trying to emit a custom event and have the directive run it's logic when it receives the event. However, I am not able to get the directive to catch the event.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Side note: I am not using Angular animation because d3 builds it's elements and it does not work with Angular animation.

File `last-seven-days-chart.component.html` and file `last-seven-days-chart.component.ts`

```html
<div class="chart-body" staggerAnimation>
  <div *ngFor="let chart of charts | async | daysFilter:7" class="last-seven-days-body">
      <line-chart
        class="hide-chart"
        [curve-data]="chart"
        graph-size="med"></line-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
export class LastSevenDaysChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public charts;
  @Output() chartsReady = new EventEmitter();

 ....

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.charts = this.getChartDataService.getData();
    this.charts.subscribe({
      complete: () => {
        // setTimeout to give time for d3 to create graphs
        setTimeout(() => this.chartsReady.emit(), 50);
      },
    });
  }
```

stagger-animation.directive.ts

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[staggerAnimation]'
})
export class StaggerAnimationDirective {

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
  ) { }

  staggerGraphs(): void {
    const chartElements = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('line-chart');
    chartElements.forEach((el, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => { el.classList.add('show-chart') }, (i * 120) );
    });
  }

  @HostListener('chartsReady', ['$event.target'])
  onChartsReady() {
    console.log('aaa'); // never get this console log
    this.staggerGraphs();
  }

}
```

Comment: Output properties are meant to be used by parent directives, but in your case the directive staggerAnimation is a child

Comment: So in `<div class="chart-body" staggerAnimation>` the component  itself `last-seven-days` is the parent?

Comment: hey just realized depending on your ChangeDetectionStrategy you might need to unsubscribe from or complete previous event emitter before subscribing again in ngOnChanges() to prevent memory leaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't think this a good use of directive and event emitter but here is how you could achieve this anyway

component.html

```
<div class="chart-body" staggerAnimation [chartsReady]="chartsReady">...</div>
```

component.ts

```
export class LastSevenDaysChartComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  public charts;
  public chartsReady = new EventEmitter();
  ...
    ngAfterViewInit() { // <-- note the lifecycle hook change
        this.charts.subscribe({
          complete: () => {
            // setTimeout to give time for d3 to create graphs
            setTimeout(() => this.chartsReady.emit(), 50);
          }
        });
      }
}
```

stagger-animation.directive.ts

```
export class StaggerAnimationDirective implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() chartsReady: EventEmitter<any>;
  ...
  ngOnChanges() {
       this.chartsReady.subscribe(this.staggerGraphs);
     }
  ngOnDestoroy() {
    this.chartsReady.unsubscribe();
  }
  ...
}
```